# How to make reference/pointer in clojure?

Tags: pointers, reference, clojure

I would like to change normal behavior of code

```
(def a 5)
(def b a)
(def a 1)
b
5
```

To this behavior

```
(def a 5)
(*something* b a)
(def a 1)
b
1
```

It is just for learning purposes so please do not try any deep sense in this.

Comment: That's not how variables in Lisp family languages work.

Comment: In Common Lisp you can do it with symbol macros. I googled and found this for you: https://github.com/clojure/tools.macro

Comment: Please, don't code in imperative style while you do functional programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an addition to Jared314's answer, I would like to point out that if you make `a` itself an atom or ref, `b` will automatically be something like a pointer or reference to `a`:

```
(def a (atom 5))
(def b a)
@b ;=> 5
(reset! a 1)
@b ;=> 1
```

Answer (score 4):

When you redefine `a`, you are not changing the value of `a` like you would in another language. It might be better to think of `a` as a constant. You have created a new `a`. This is part of the design philosophy of Clojure.

If you want something like a pointer, take a look at [refs](http://clojure.org/refs) and [atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms).

Atom:

```
(def a 5)
(def b (atom a))
@b ;=> 5
(def a 1)
@b ;=> 5
(reset! b a)
@b ;=> 1
```

Ref:

```
(def a 5)
(def b (ref a))
@b ;=> 5
(def a 1)
@b ;=> 5
(dosync
 (ref-set b a))
@b ;=> 1
```

**Note:** the `@` is used to dereference `b`. It is shorthand for the `deref` function, and is required to get the value of `b`.